# Sandisk Ultra 3.0 128GB USB can't be detected on my Mac or Windows 10 after removing it

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, external-disk, disk-format

I bought a Sandisk Ultra 3.0 128GB USB for my Mac, a few years ago, so I could move files to windows if I wanted. All was well and working fine until I accidentally unplugged the USB from my Mac while transferring a file to it. Now my Mac is no longer able to detect the USB, and my Windows 10 desktop can see it but can no longer read it. It shows up but is is showing that it has 0 gigs

Here are some facts:

•   The USB doesn't show up on Mac in system information, disk utility, recovery mode, or when I put in the command I found to show the active drives in Terminal... It seems to have become completely invisible. (I've made sure that Finder isn't hiding it)

•   On my Mac I've tried restarting / shutting off the machine, as well as resetting the VRAM and the SMC.

•   My Mac can still detect other USB storage devices when I plug those in.

It's a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2015) running OS X Yosemite.
Any tech genius out there with a solution or some sort of idea / suggestion?

Any idea would be appreciated. It seems the USB is no longer working, I just have no idea how to get the two machines to detect it so I can repair it or so I can get the files off it.

Comment: I have seen this happen where a Mac will not even see a drive and a Windows PC will see it but can't do anything with it. Assuming the USB ports on the Mac were not harmed and are otherwise working fine, I would tend to think that yanking a drive during a write operation has damaged the drive beyond the abilities of the basic tools available on macOS and Windows to repair it.

Comment: Never tried this app, but I use this developer's media converter app. [Wondershare Recoverit Data Recovery](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/flashdrive-recovery/recover-files-from-corrupted-flash-drive.html?/topic/200-printing-to-a-pdf-where-is-the-file/&gclid=CjwKCAjwrKr8BRB_EiwA7eFapkNxLFow6YXuo7cEs8goIUhG8LBmSwy4ignsLRfGShUirCMPmPYp5RoCzb4QAvD_BwE). _Disclaimer: satisfied customer of Wondershare - no financial or other ties to the company._

Comment: Thank you I will try Wondershare. I own this app.  I'm not sure it will work because the drive is showing 0gb on the PC and it can't be read by the Mac.  What do I have to loose right?